# Weakly and Strongly connected components in an Undirected vs Directed graph

Tags: graph-theory

I have a tool where, if I insert a graph, it gives me back the number of **weakly connected components** and the **strongly connected components**.

When I insert any undirected graph, the numbers of these two properties are the same.

When I insert any directed graph, the numbers of these two properties are different.

Is this indeed correct? If so, why is the undirected the same?

Comment: The definitions of "weakly connected" and "strongly connected" **only makes sense in a directed graph**.  In an undirected graph, there is only the concept of "connected" (*or $n$-connected in general*), so if you ask the question of weakly/strongly connected on an undirected graph, it is presumably assuming that every edge in the graph is directed in both directions, thus making every weakly connected component a strongly connected component as well and thus the count is the same.  Note that for directed graphs it is possible (*but doesn't always happen*) that the numbers are the same as well

Comment: The only additional missing information from my earlier post that I linked to is that weakly/strongly connected *components* are those maximal subgraphs such that they are weakly/strongly connected (*maximal in the sense that no set of additional vertices or edges may be added that keeps it weakly/strongly connected*).

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks a lot for the clarity! Appreciate it! Can it be that the naming for undirected graphs is simply ''connected components''? Or is the notion of components here invalid and is simply ''n-connected'' like you mentioned?

Comment: [Connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_(graph_theory)) are indeed a thing.  The [$n$-connectivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connectivity_(graph_theory)#Connected_graph) (vertex-connectivity) is more about what the smallest number of vertices (*or edges for edge-connectivity*) are that need to be deleted to disconnect the graph.

Comment: Thanks! :) feel free to post your comments as an answer and I'll accept it!